# Finding bounds of leaflet tile after loading

Tags: leaflet

I have a leaflet map, and I am trying to load some information from a server dynamically, whenever a new tile loads, to create an overlay.

In order to test this, the first thing I tried was simply creating in the onTileLoad event a transparent rectangle the same size as the loaded tile. I'm doing this by pulling the tile X/Y out of the loaded URL, and then using code from this page: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Derivation_of_tile_names to convert it to a latitude/longitude.

Strangely, the only way I have been able to make the polygon appear in the correct location is with the following code:

```
function onTileLoad(e) {
    var tile=e.url.split("/");
    var z=tile[tile.length-3];
    var x=tile[tile.length-2];
    var y=tile[tile.length-1].split(".")[0];
    //console.log("x:"+x+"y"+y+"z"+z);

    var southWest = new L.LatLng(tile2lat(y, z), tile2long(x-(-1.0), z)), 
        northEast = new L.LatLng(tile2lat(y-(-1.0), z), tile2long(x, z)),
        bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);


    //console.log("southwest: "+southWest+" northEast: "+northEast);

    L.rectangle(bounds, {color: "#ff7800", weight: 1}).addTo(map);
```

You'll notice that the northeast corner is created by: y-(-1.0)

If I make that (y+1.0) instead, which should be the same thing, it loads the rectangle in the wrong coordinates, overlapping already loaded tiles.

So my questions are:

1) Why is y - (-1.0) not the same as (y+1.0)?
2) Is there a better way to be getting the bounds of a newly loaded tile?

Thanks!

Comment: JavaScript will interpret + as string concatenation I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

you using

> (float.pasre(y)+float.pasre(1.0))?2)

, it'll working.